# Finding a vector perpendicular to a given vector in 3 dimensional space

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, inner-products, solid-geometry

So if I have points $A(2, 6,-1)$ and $B(-3, 2, 8)$ that create vector $\vec{AB}$. I want to create perpendicular vector $\vec{AC}$, which has the same starting point $A$ and then unknown end point $C(x, y, z)$. If I also knew that $\vec{AC}$ has magnitude $3$, how do I then determine the point $C$?

Comment: Perpendicular to a non-zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec{AC}(a,b,c)$.

Thus, $a^2+b^2+c^2=9$ and since $$\vec{AB}(-5,-4,9),$$ we obtain:
$$-5a-4b+9c=0$$ and we got infinitely many these vectors and these points $C$.

If we want that $AC||DE$, where $\vec{DE}(14,5,3)$ then $a=14k$,$b=5k$, $c=3k$ and you can check  if this possible.

Comment: So what happens then if I'd like it to be parrallel to a vector DE that goes from D (-5, 2, 0) to E (9, 7, 3). Sorry for maybe stupid questions, but it has been a long time since I've had to deal with stuff like this..

Comment: @Kp222 In $\mathbb R^3$, you can compute $\overrightarrow{AC}\times\overrightarrow{DE}$ to get a vector that’s perpendicular to them both, then adjust it to the desired length.